# Create iOS Wizard in one scene

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I want to create a setup wizard for a swift application. I have done this several times before but every time I make this by creating several scenes with several view controllers. This time, I don't want to make it this way. I want to have web view control in the background that will contain GIF and I want this GIF to be playing across the whole wizard lifecycle. This means that I want **One** Scene with **One** Viewcontroller and when the user swipes or presses next, The questions should swipe leaving the background GIF playing. I want to know the best practice for doing such thing. I have seen it in several apps. I thought about creating one large view and adding a gesture recognizer and when the user swipe I would animate it to the right or left. Please note that my questions in the wizard are dynamic and every page should have totally new format of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I would recommend you to use `UIPageViewController` to create the wizard/tutorial in iOS. Here is an example implementing it. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/

Comment: Yes, I have used it before. But It's not that good for dynamic content. I must change the place of every control programmatically to be able to do what I want.

Comment: Why no good? You could create only one content view controller and let this view controller (or the root view controller) load the dynamic content for you.

Comment: I mean by dynamic, Dynamic in controls & positions. One page you have 3 text fields, the other page you have a table view, etc..

Comment: So to use pageview I must create everything programmatically instead of scenes on Xcode

Comment: Then create these controls in each of the content view controllers. That is exactly what `UIPageViewController` is capable of. This is the simplest way to achieve it.

Comment: You can still use storyboard to create the content views. Add your controls to each of the content view in storyboard. In the code you only manage the transition of views.

Comment: Maybe i didn't use it well. Ill give it another try. Thank you for ur support